# Loop Invariance rule deduction from Reflexive transitive closure rule

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Would anyone care to explain how can we deduce the Loop Invariance rule from the Reflexive Transitive Closure rule in PDL:

$$\frac{\psi\rightarrow (\phi\vee [\alpha]\psi)}{\psi\rightarrow [\alpha^*]\phi}$$?
to: $$\frac{(\phi\vee\langle\alpha\rangle\psi)\rightarrow\psi}{\langle\alpha^*\rangle\phi\rightarrow\psi}$$

I've already deduced that $$\frac{(\phi\vee\langle\alpha\rangle\psi)\rightarrow\psi}{\langle\alpha^*\rangle\phi\rightarrow\psi}$$
is equivalent to
$$ \frac{\psi \rightarrow [\alpha]\psi}{\psi \rightarrow [\alpha^*]\psi} \enspace, $$
if that helps.

Where $\alpha$ is a program, $\phi,\psi$ are formulas and $\langle\alpha\rangle$ is the diamond from PDL.

Comment: Is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2103826/123852) what you are looking for?

Comment: I just noted that you asked the other question as well.  The last rule you show is the loop invariance rule and $\psi$ is the invariant, while $\alpha$ is the loop body.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Now I'm trying to deduce $\psi\rightarrow\phi$ and $\psi\rightarrow[\alpha]\phi$ from the last rule.

Comment: From the loop invariance rule alone, you cannot derive $\psi \rightarrow \psi$.  However, if you assume $\psi \rightarrow \psi$ and $\psi \rightarrow [\alpha]\psi$, then the loop invariance rule allows you to conclude that $\psi \rightarrow [\alpha^*]\phi$.

Comment: Also note that the invariance rule is not equivalent to the dual of the reflexive transitive closure rule.  Rather, it's a special case of it.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Thanks alot for both suggestions and explanations!

Comment: You are welcome.  Actually, I mistyped in one of the comments above.  I meant $\psi \rightarrow \phi$, not the tautologous $\psi \rightarrow \psi$.